# htaccess rederect to another page but not the pages/folder under

Tags: .htaccess

using a .htaccess to rederect a page but don't whant to rederect the sub folders as example below of the code using.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ link/$1 [P,R]
```

whant to put a condition that if the url contains the word admin doesn't rederect have ben told that have to use

> RewriteCond

but I am a complete begginer at .htaccess could someone help how to write that condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ link/$1 [P,R]
```